# How to add character spacing in Date in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetimepicker

```
string d1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd MM yyyy");
```

[image]

if I add space myself

```
string d1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("d  d  M  M  y  y  y  y");
```

it becomes like this:

[image]

Editing: just re-editing my post about my desired result.

From this: `28/12/2015` to

Desired Result is:  `2  8  1  2  2  0  1  5`

Spacing in date.

Comment: Look at the mdsn doc for DateTime and you'll see why the spacing behaves this way.

Comment: How do you want the output to be displayed?

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you wanna get `0 8 0 9 2 0 1 5`, right? By the way, these `d`, `M` and `y` are also custom date and time specifiers as well.

Comment: @SonerGönül yes I want it like that, one you showed above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i suggest to insert spaces after you convert DateTime to String

```
string d1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("  ", d1.AsEnumerable()));
```

result is `0  8  0  9  2  0  1  5`

Comment: Or `String.Join("  ", (IEnumerable<char>)d1)` - anything that avoids `String.Join(string,string)`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, it is *almost* the same. `d1.AsEnumerable()` needs `using System.Linq`